# How to start WCF service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I've got a solution consisting of two projects: an ASP.NET Web Application project and a WCF Service Application project.

When running the solution from within the VS 2010 IDE, two browser windows are started. One browser displays the ASP.NET form page, and the other browser showing a directory listing very much like this:

> Directory Listing -- /
>
> ```
> Saturday, December 18, 2010 10:40 PM        <dir> App_Data
> Monday,   December 20, 2010 10:10 PM        <dir> bin
> Saturday, December 18, 2010 10:53 PM          111 ChatService.svc
> Thursday, December 30, 2010 10:41 PM          455 ChatService.svc.cs
> Friday, December 31, 2010 03:27 PM        <dir> DataLayer
> Monday, December 20, 2010 11:32 PM          265 IChatService.cs
> Saturday, December 18, 2010 10:40 PM        <dir> obj
> Saturday, December 18, 2010 10:40 PM        <dir> Properties
> Friday, December 31, 2010 03:33 PM        4,609 Services.csproj
> Friday, December 31, 2010 03:33 PM        1,086 Services.csproj.user
> Sunday, December 19, 2010 08:35 AM           58 Services.Publish.xml
> Monday, December 20, 2010 02:09 PM          959 Web.config
> Saturday, December 18, 2010 10:40 PM          247 Web.Debug.config
> Saturday, December 18, 2010 10:40 PM          343 Web.Release.config
> ```
>
> Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0

The second browser window (with the directory listing) is obviously the WCF service. Now, is there a way to suppress the WCF service browser window, or is this the expected behavior since the WCF Service Application project is self-hosted?

Also, I've got the solution properties set to multiple startup projects.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the normal behavior when running a WCF Service Application project. I believe you can suppress this by going to project properties, Web tab, and selecting "Don't open a page."

Answer (score 0):

See wcf service properties. There is option named something like "Start WCF Service". You need to check this option.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find that kind of option.